# Benchmarking currency trading strategy

Tags: currency, benchmark

I am backtesting a currency trading strategy where the base currency is the USD. I am looking for a benchmark to compare the results. Since currency trading is an active investment, I do not think that the buy-and-hold approach will work. I remember reading that usually, currency trading strategies are benchmarked against the return to "cash", which in the USD case often means comparing to the 3-month Treasury bill. What does this mean specifically? How can I calculate the returns for this benchmark? Is it like just buying Treasury bills every 3-months and accumulating the return?

Comment: "I remember reading that usually, currency trading strategies are benchmarked against the return to "cash"" - this doesn't make sense to me as the risk profile of holding TBills and your strategy are likely to be very different. 'Benchmarks' I've seen for FX strategies have typically been other, common FX strategies such as value or carry. But depending on what your strategy does, these might not be relevant.

Comment: @user42108 but I would still like to know how the TBill benchmark is constructed. It could be useful for me to see how the returns change as the risk changes.

Comment: This is the starting point https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/TB3MS You could for example assume that you earn a return equal to a quarter of this rate every 3 months.

Comment: "I would still like to know how the TBill benchmark is constructed" - Bloomberg and Barclays have indices of returns for T-bills. Might be worth checking if documentation on index construction is available. I'm sure there are others, but that's the one I know offhand.